# creating unique code for nested XML using element tree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I've below nested XML code. Refer image below

[image: this image for more clarity]

1. Yellow Highlighted codes are `1st Layer`
2. Blue Highlighted codes are `2nd Layer`
3. Red Highlighted codes are `3rd Layer`

`refer below for the xml data`

```
<trx><invoice>27844173</invoice><total>52</total><item><code>110</code></item><item><code>304</code><items><item><code>54</code><items><item><code>174</code></item><item><code>600</code></item></items></item><item><code>478</code></item><item><code>810</code></item></items></item></trx>
```

My task is to create unique ids for all 3 layers. and below is my code I wrote.

```
import pandas as pd 
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml_file_path = 'C:\Desktop\data.xml'

tree = ET.parse(xml_file_path)
root = tree.getroot()

sub_item_id = 0


cols = ['invoice','total','code','item_id','A','B','C']

dict_xml = {}
data = []
for trx in root.iter('trx'):

    invoice = trx.find('invoice').text
    total = trx.find('total').text

    item_id = 0

    a = 0
    for it in trx.findall('item'):
        a += 1
        b = -1
        for j in it.iter('item'):
            b += 1
            c = 0

            code = j.find('code').text

            item_id += 1    


            data.append({"invoice":invoice,"total":total,"code":code,
                         "item_id":item_id,"A":a,"B":b,"C":c})


data = pd.DataFrame(data)
data
```

And I get below output. where `Column A` is correct. not `B and C`

```
+---+----------+-------+------+---------+---+---+---+
|   | invoice  | total | code | item_id | A | B | C |
+---+----------+-------+------+---------+---+---+---+
| 0 | 27844173 |   52  |  110 |    1    | 1 | 0 | 0 |
+---+----------+-------+------+---------+---+---+---+
| 1 | 27844173 |   52  |  304 |    2    | 2 | 0 | 0 |
+---+----------+-------+------+---------+---+---+---+
| 2 | 27844173 |   52  |  54  |    3    | 2 | 1 | 0 |
+---+----------+-------+------+---------+---+---+---+
| 3 | 27844173 |   52  |  174 |    4    | 2 | 2 | 0 |
+---+----------+-------+------+---------+---+---+---+
| 4 | 27844173 |   52  |  600 |    5    | 2 | 3 | 0 |
+---+----------+-------+------+---------+---+---+---+
| 5 | 27844173 |   52  |  478 |    6    | 2 | 4 | 0 |
+---+----------+-------+------+---------+---+---+---+
| 6 | 27844173 |   52  |  810 |    7    | 2 | 5 | 0 |
+---+----------+-------+------+---------+---+---+---+
```

My expected result is as below.

```
+---+----------+-------+------+---------+---+---+---+
|   | invoice  | total | code | item_id | A | B | C |
+---+----------+-------+------+---------+---+---+---+
| 0 | 27844173 |   52  |  110 |    1    | 1 | 0 | 0 |
+---+----------+-------+------+---------+---+---+---+
| 1 | 27844173 |   52  |  304 |    2    | 2 | 0 | 0 |
+---+----------+-------+------+---------+---+---+---+
| 2 | 27844173 |   52  |  54  |    3    | 2 | 1 | 0 |
+---+----------+-------+------+---------+---+---+---+
| 3 | 27844173 |   52  |  174 |    4    | 2 | 1 | 1 |
+---+----------+-------+------+---------+---+---+---+
| 4 | 27844173 |   52  |  600 |    5    | 2 | 1 | 2 |
+---+----------+-------+------+---------+---+---+---+
| 5 | 27844173 |   52  |  478 |    6    | 2 | 2 | 0 |
+---+----------+-------+------+---------+---+---+---+
| 6 | 27844173 |   52  |  810 |    7    | 2 | 3 | 0 |
+---+----------+-------+------+---------+---+---+---+
```

how and where should I increment `B and C` variables to get the desired output

Comment: What's the logic behind the A, B and C column values?

Comment: `B and C`are nested items `2nd and 3rd` layers. respectively. 
Eg, Code `110 and 304` are 1st Layer. This is `A`
Code `54 , 478 and 810 ` are children of `304`. Hence, 2nd layer. This is `B`
Similarly  code `174 and 600` are children of `54` and grandchildren of `304`. Hence, 3rd Layer.This is `C`

Comment: Can you also edit your question and post the xml as code, not just as an image?

Comment: @JackFleeting XML code is already present under `refer below for the xml data` section. I added the image for extra clarity.

Comment: this one `<trx><invoice>27844173</invoice><total>52</total><item><code>110</code></item><item><code>304</code><items><item><code>54</code><items><item><code>174</code></item><item><code>600</code></item></items></item><item><code>478</code></item><item><code>810</code></item></items></item></trx>`

Comment: You're right - sorry, didn't notice that.

Comment: no worries. would appreciate a solution please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A preliminary observation first: while you used xml.etree, I prefer using the lxml library because of it has better support for xpath. Obviously, you can try to convert the code to xml.etree if you feel it's necessary.

There may be shorter ways of doing this, but for the time being let's use the following and I'll explain along the way:

```
import pandas as pd
from lxml import etree

stuff = """[your xml above]"""

doc = etree.XML(stuff.encode())
tree = etree.ElementTree(doc)

#first off, get the invoice number and total as integers
inv = int(doc.xpath('/trx/invoice/text()')[0])
total = int(doc.xpath('/trx/total/text()')[0])

#initialize a few lists:
levels = [] #we'll need this to determine programmatically how many levels deep the xml is
codes = [] #collect the codes
tiers = [] #create rows for each tier

#next - how many levels deep is the xml? Not easy to find out:
for e in doc.iter('item'):
    path = tree.getpath(e)
    tier = path.replace('/trx/','').replace('item','').replace('/s/',' ').replace('[','').replace(']','')
    tiers.append(tier.split(' '))
    codes.append(e.xpath('./code/text()')[0])
    levels.append(path.count('[')) #we now have the depth of each tier

#the length of each tier is a function of its level; so we pad the length of that list to the highest level number (3 in this example):
for tier in tiers:
    tiers[tiers.index(tier)] = [*tier, *["0"] * (max(levels)-len(tier))]
    #so all that work with counting levels was just to use this max(levels) variable once...

#we now insert the other info you require in each row:
for t,c in zip(tiers,codes):
    t.insert(0,c)
    t.insert(0,inv)
    t.insert(0,total)

   
#With all this prep out of the way, we get to the dataframe at last:
ids = list(range(1, len(tiers)+1)) #this is for the additional column you require
columns = ["total","invoice","code"," A"," B","C"]
df = pd.DataFrame(tiers,columns=columns)
df.insert(2, 'item_id', ids) #insert the extra column
df
```

Output:

```
 total invoice item_id code     A   B   C
0   52  27844173    1   110     1   0   0
1   52  27844173    2   304     2   0   0
2   52  27844173    3   54      2   1   0
3   52  27844173    4   174     2   1   1
4   52  27844173    5   600     2   1   2
5   52  27844173    6   478     2   2   0
6   52  27844173    7   810     2   3   0
```

Comment: Thanks. This answer works well with the given example data. I applied this to other scenarios and found that whenever only one item in the 3rd layer. it doesn't give `1` instead blank ` ` . eg, if we remove either `174` or `600` scenarios.  
I guess, I can replace those values from the DataFrame to `1` after final conversion. upvoted and accepted the answer.

Comment: also I'm not familiar with `lxml`. so I'm not sure how to change this code. eg, `(1)` rather than typing the code, I want to load via a file. `(2)` in this one xml data I had only one invoice. But, in my actual data it has many invoice. so i want loop through each invoice and produce the complete DataFrame.

Comment: @Tommy as to (1) there are many examples for that: for instance https://stackoverflow.com/a/42901996/9448090. As to (2), yes, you'll have to create a loop to do that - just like any other loop, it has nothing to do with lxml as such. If you run into difficulties, you may want to post it as a separate question.

Comment: Sure, will give this a try and post a separate question in case of any issues. Thank you and really appreciate for taking the time to solve this question.